# Elasticsearch multi term query rewrite

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to understand how to use Elasticsearch properly and stumbled at the concept of [multi term query rewrite](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-term-rewrite.html).

My question is what does it do exactly? Does it simply affect score calculation or it changes the whole query being parsed? Or does it do something else? Any light would be appreciated!

PS: Looking at [this](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/fuzzy-matching-and-direct-hit-ranking-td3988602.html) thread sort of suggests me that it has something to do with fuzzy score calculation.